# Deleting files on SDCard; The device thinks the files don't exist even though they do

Tags: android, sd-card, delete-file

I'm facing a problem in the following code. What I'm trying to do is delete a folder and all of it's contents. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

```
boolean success = false;

String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

directory += "/.SID/Downloads/DC0601";

File path = new File(directory);

File[] files;

try 
{
    files = path.listFiles();

    if (files == null)
    {
        success = path.delete();
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i ++)
        {
            File currentFile = files[i];

            if (currentFile != null)
                currentFile.delete();
        }

        success = path.delete();
    }
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    success = false;
    Log.e("deleteData Exception: ", e.toString());
}
```

What's happening here is that in some cases, the directory 'DC0601' does exist and does contain files on the sdcard, but when this code runs, success is returned as false because 'files' is null. Why is it null?!!

I simply can't understand it. If I completely shut down the app and then run it, it can detect the files and the directory and can successfully delete them. Otherwise if I've been using the app for a while and then run the code, it thinks that directory and those files aren't there.

Has anyone faced similar issues with `delete()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're grabbing the external storage directory, but I don't see you checking it's state.

What does `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` return?

Comment: According to File.listFiles(): "The result is null if this file is not a directory."

Comment: Okay. But when I close the process, and connect the SDCard for USB Storage, I can see the folder there, with all the files inside....

Answer (score 1):

Should you be using

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

I've never actually used .toString().

Comment: Nope... that didn't help :( Thanks though